# Can't manipulate data from $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use the result of an Ajax query in order to set the value of an input.
The problem is that I get an empty result ([Object object])
Here is my process :

First : I realise a simple query and encode the result in JSON :

**file : getVar.php**

```
    //getMyVar($id) runs a simple "select" query with a specified id
    // SELECT name FROM table where id = id
    $var= getMyVar($id);


    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($var);
```

Then, I (try to) extract the data and I insert it as a value in an input which has the id "name"

*Note : I am sure of the input's id.*

**file : printStuff.js**

```
        request = $.post('getVar.php', {id:id}, 'json');

        request.done(function(data){        
        $('#name').val(data.name);
        });
```

When I inspect my page in my browser with firebug, I can see that my first page `(getVar.php)` returns a well formatted `JSON` result.

```
{"id":"42","name":"test"}
```

So, I think that the error occurs when I try to extract the data form the $.post

If you need any additional information, don't hesitate :)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you're getting `[Object object]` it tells you that `data.name` is not a string, but an object, and that you need to console log it to see what it really is

Comment: what exactly is `getMyVar()` doing? We can't help you with any of this since that's not a standard function and we have NO idea what it's doing.

Comment: oh soory, forgot to mention it, getMyVar is a function that execute a simple Select request

Comment: `console.log(data);` What does it return in the console? Is it what you expect?

Comment: it seems to retrieve the right result (a string)

Comment: And `console.log(data.name);` returns the right value?

Comment: Don't know if I recall seeing a post done without a success method before, and it probably is fine, but do you suppose you could try ` request = $.post('getVar.php', {id:id}, function () {}, 'json');` or ` request = $.post('getVar.php', {id:id});` ?

Comment: do you need to do something like this: `var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data); console.log(jsonData.name);`

Comment: Sorry for being so late to answer, I was a bit in a hurry
So, I tested your different suggestions and it helped me a lot.
With the differents console.logs and @Being Human's answer I finally succeed to get my beloved variables back :)

To resume : 
getVar.php :
`die(json_encode(array('status'=>'success','name'=>$var)));`

printStuff.js : 
`console.log(data.status);
console.log(data.name);
if(data.status=='success'){
  $('#name').val(data.name);
 }`

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to debug you `data` and encode your data from server side using `json_encode()`

```
  //getVar.php
  $var= getMyVar($id);
  die(json_encode(array('status'=>'success','name'=>$var)))

  //javascript code
$.post("getVar.php",{id:id}, 'json').done(function( data ) 
  {
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.name);
    if(data.status=='success'){
      $('#name').val(data.name);
    }
  });
```